# How to check battery status with the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, battery, qml

I am developing an app and I need to monitor the battery status, with the SDK how do I obtain the devices (phone) battery status? can this be done with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using QtSystemInfo which is in the [qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin [image: Install qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin) package.

There is a more complete  [demo in the upstream git repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtsystems/raw/26c9f7c7d05a4286f7011a2b60cb0925a4a2555c:examples/systeminfo/qml-battery/qml-battery.qml) that shows how you can check various battery properties in pure QML/JavaScript. Here's a quick example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtSystemInfo 5.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: root
    width: units.gu(50)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        id: home
        visible: true
        title: "Battery Info"

        BatteryInfo {
            id: batinfo
            property real percentage: 0

            monitorRemainingCapacity: true
            monitorChargingState: true

            onRemainingCapacityChanged: {
                var battery = 0
                batinfo.percentage = (100/batinfo.maximumCapacity(battery)*batinfo.remainingCapacity(battery)).toFixed(1)
                level.text = percentage + "%"
            }
        }

        UbuntuShape {
            id: image
            anchors.bottom: level.top
            anchors.horizontalCenter: level.horizontalCenter
            anchors.margins: units.gu(2)
            image: Image {
                // here you would obviously want differet icons based on the percentage, but I'm lazy
                source: Qt.resolvedUrl("/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mobile/status/scalable/battery_full.svg")
            }
        }

        Label {
            id: level
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            fontSize: "x-large"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: battery-info]